# PM2 deploy failed with "Not a git repository" message

Tags: pm2

I encounter a problem in the deployment of my project with pm2.
I have seen several issues on the subject but they are all closed and no solution is proposed in them.

I have successfully done this command 
`pm2 deploy ecosystem.config.js preproduction setup`

but when I try to deploy
`pm2 deploy ecosystem.config.js preproduction`

I have this error :

```
Not a git repository
To compare two paths outside a working tree:
usage: git diff [--no-index] <path> <path>

  commit or stash your changes before deploying

Deploy failed
```

here is my ecosystem.config.js

```js
module.exports = {
  apps: [
    {
      "name": "swizi-chat",
      "script": "./src/index.js",
      "env-preproduction": {

      },
    },
  ],
  deploy: {
    preproduction: {
      "host": "x.x.x.x",
      "user": "node",
      "ref": "origin/master",
      "repo": "git@gitlab.com:myproject.git",
      "path": "/var/nodejs/my-project",
      "post-deploy":
        "npm install && pm2 reload ecosystem.config.js --env preproduction && pm2 save",
    },
  },
};
```

pm2 version is 4.2.3

Thx for your help

Answer (score 1):

Use `--force`.

```sh
pm2 deploy ecosystem.config.js production --force
```

[PM2 Deploy Documentation](https://pm2.keymetrics.io/docs/usage/deployment/)

> Note: if git report an error that there are local changes but still want to push what is on the remote GIT, you can use the --force option to force deployment.

Comment: Works for me, everything was added/commit/pushed, repository was cleaned, git status or diff gave me no changes, git reset was done but pm2 was still refusing to deploy. Adding --force resole the issue

Answer (score -1):

I had the same issue and this worked for me:

I created another git repository only with my `ecosystem.config.js` file and push the changes I made on it each time I want to run a deploy, even if it's a local one.

pm2 version - 4.4.0

Comment: Please make the answering part of this more obvious. It seems more like a detailed "Me too." which is not considered an appropriate answer on StackOverflow and risks being deleted as such.